# Isometric grid responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sass

Can someone guide me how I can obtain something like this?

[image: isometric grid]

It has to be responsive, and the elements to be arrange like in the image.

Answer (score 3):

At the most basic level, each element could use a css transform like so:

```
element {
  transform: rotateX(60deg) rotateZ(-45deg);
}
```

As per the grid, using a wrapper with css `columns`, or `display: flex` with widths & heights set on the children should achieve what you're looking for.

However, by saying 'it has to be responsive' you're implying a whole lot. What do you mean by that, specifically? Do you want it to scale? Crop? Scroll? There are several ways you could do each of these things. Either by using viewport units or percentages for the wrapper width, for example. Or centering it within the page, and setting overflow to hidden (if you'd like the edges to be cropped). In the future, it would be helpful if you were more specific with those kinds of questions. Anyway, hope that helps.

Comment: By responsive i mean to scale down with the browser width, thank you for your answear.